# how to assert a pointer's pointed content is on heap?

Tags: c++, pointers

how to assert a pointer's pointed content is on heap? For example

```
int i;
int* p1 = &i;
int* p2 = new int;
assert(!onHeap(p1));
assert(onHeap(p2));
```

Comment: There is no portable way of doing this.

Comment: what is the way in windows?

Comment: @juanchopanza There kind of is … override `operator new` (and maybe `malloc`) to introduce your own bookkeeping.

Comment: @KonradRudolph If the pointer is allocated by a 3rd-party library...

Comment: @user1899020 Depending on how you link the library that might still work (but, yes, it probably won’t).